# Close detail page and return to home

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigationservice

In my application, I have list of news... When user click on some item, I navigate him to page with detail:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Detail.xaml?ID=" + listbox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
```

On this detail page are also button `prev` and `next`, which navigate to next and previous items (also to `Detail.xaml`, just ID is increased or decreased by 1). However, if user go through some news and want to return to "homepage", he needs to push Back button many times. Is there any way, how can I just close this `Detail.xaml`? Open it modal or something? I don't want to use "go home" button, which just navigate user to main page because of loop when he tries to exit application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the next or previous buttons are clicked try calling `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` in the `OnNavigatedTo` method. This will remove the page from the back stack, thus ensuring that when they hit the back button they return to the index page.

Comment: Thank you very much! All I need to do is check if `Detail.xaml` is not navigated from home page (as you said, only next and previous button otherwise application will be closed after going back) and than it works how i need.